# extjs 6.0 sencha cmd to compile only my javascript code

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I use sencha extjs 6.0 ,and it always compile all extjs  code to single one file .What I need is that :
1 the need extjs is compiled to one single file ,I know which packages are needed ,so it can be static and not need to change .
2 then sencha cmd compile my own javascript file to one single file ,so I can update to web server and let client  download it less size file .Because the extjs file size is large than 600K with compression .
Anyone have idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into `.sencha/app/production.properties` and add a new line:

```
enable.split.mode=true
```

Then compile, and you should get two files, one big `framework.js` and one smaller `app.js`.

Comment: when I use this method ,the framwork.js is small and the app.js is large .Everytime I build it ,it always  change the two files .

Comment: What I want it is the framework.js is large and static file ,and the app.js is changed everytime when I build .Can this be done ?