# ExtJS: Override all AJAX calls in production build

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, ant, extjs6

What I'm trying to do is override all AJAX requests, including AJAX proxies, so what I created was an override for Ext.data.Connection. In development mode, this works like a charm, but in a production build, things get a little weird.

The reason why things get weird is because we're doing something that "splits" the build ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45122418/1253609)). Meaning, we put all of the framework code into its own file, then have "app.js," which is essentially what we use for booting our application, and "viewport.js," which is the actual application after the booting succeeds. We do this because in "app.js," we have an auth call which makes sure the user is valid, and if they are, then we load "viewport.js."

I think the problem with this is, because we're overriding such a core piece of functionality, it doesn't actually get overridden until app.js loads, which, at that point, Ext.Ajax--a singleton of the overridden class Ext.data.Connection--has already been created, and we lose out on overriding that. It looks like the override is included in app.js, so this assumption would make sense.

I think what needs to happen is that the build.xml needs to include this override in the framework.js file, but I really don't know how to do that... I've never dealt with Ant, so I'm not even sure where I would start. If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be super helpful. This is what the build.xml looks like right now (see begin custom addition comment for where we added the split code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="NewApp" default=".help">

    <!-- Find and load Sencha Cmd ant tasks -->
    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            var dir = project.getProperty("basedir"),
                cmdDir = project.getProperty("cmd.dir"),
                cmdLoaded = project.getReference("senchaloader");

            if (!cmdLoaded) {
                function echo(message, file) {
                    var e = project.createTask("echo");
                    e.setMessage(message);
                    if (file) {
                        e.setFile(file);
                    }
                    e.execute();
                };

                if (!cmdDir) {

                    function exec(args) {
                        var process = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args),
                            input = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())),
                            headerFound = false,
                            line;

                        while (line = input.readLine()) {
                            line = line + '';
                            java.lang.System.out.println(line);
                            if (line.indexOf("Sencha Cmd") > -1) {
                                headerFound = true;
                            }
                            else if (headerFound && !cmdDir) {
                                cmdDir = line;
                                project.setProperty("cmd.dir", cmdDir);
                            }
                        }
                        process.waitFor();
                        return !!cmdDir;
                    }

                    if (!exec(["sencha", "which"])) {
                        var tmpFile = "tmp.sh";
                        echo("source ~/.bash_profile; sencha " + whichArgs.join(" "), tmpFile);
                        exec(["/bin/sh", tmpFile]);
                        new java.io.File(tmpFile)['delete']();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (cmdDir && !project.getTargets().containsKey("init-cmd")) {
                var importDir = project.getProperty("build-impl.dir") ||
                                (cmdDir + "/ant/build/app/build-impl.xml");
                var importTask = project.createTask("import");

                importTask.setOwningTarget(self.getOwningTarget());
                importTask.setLocation(self.getLocation());
                importTask.setFile(importDir);
                importTask.execute();
            }
        ]]>
    </script>

    <!--
    The following targets can be provided to inject logic before and/or after key steps
    of the build process:

        The "init-local" target is used to initialize properties that may be personalized
        for the local machine.

            <target name="-before-init-local"/>
            <target name="-after-init-local"/>

        The "clean" target is used to clean build output from the build.dir.

            <target name="-before-clean"/>
            <target name="-after-clean"/>

        The general "init" target is used to initialize all other properties, including
        those provided by Sencha Cmd.

            <target name="-before-init"/>
            <target name="-after-init"/>

        The "page" target performs the call to Sencha Cmd to build the 'all-classes.js' file.

            <target name="-before-page"/>
            <target name="-after-page"/>

        The "build" target performs the call to Sencha Cmd to build the application.

            <target name="-before-build"/>
            <target name="-after-build"/>
    -->
    <!-- BEGIN CUSTOM ADDITION TO BUILD.XML -->
    <target name="-after-js">
        <!-- The following is derived from the compile-js target in
             .sencha/app/js-impl.xml. Compile the viewport and all of its
             dependencies into viewport.js. Include in the framework
             dependencies in the framework file. -->
        <x-compile refid="${compiler.ref.id}">
            <![CDATA[
            union
              -r
              -class=${app.name}.view.main.Main
            and
            save
              viewport
            and
            intersect
              -set=viewport,allframework
            and
            include
              -set=frameworkdeps
            and
            save
              frameworkdeps
            and
            include
              -tag=Ext.cmd.derive
            and
            concat
              -remove-text-references=${build.remove.references}
              -optimize-string-references=${build.optimize.string.references}
              -remove-requirement-nodes=${build.remove.requirement.nodes}
              ${build.compression}
              -out=${build.framework.file}
              ${build.concat.options}
            and
            restore
              viewport
            and
            exclude
              -set=frameworkdeps
            and
            exclude
              -set=page
            and
            exclude
              -tag=Ext.cmd.derive,derive
            and
            concat
              -remove-text-references=${build.remove.references}
              -optimize-string-references=${build.optimize.string.references}
              -remove-requirement-nodes=${build.remove.requirement.nodes}
              ${build.compression}
              -out=${build.out.base.path}/${build.id}/viewport.js
              ${build.concat.options}
            ]]>
        </x-compile>

        <!-- Concatenate the file that sets the main view. -->
        <concat destfile="${build.out.base.path}/${build.id}/viewport.js" append="true">
            <fileset file="classic/viewport.js"/>
        </concat>
    </target>

    <target name="-before-sass">
        <!-- The viewport is not explicitly required by the application,
             however, its SCSS dependencies need to be included. Unfortunately,
             the property required to filter the output, sass.name.filter, is
             declared as local and cannot be overridden. Use the development
             configuration instead. -->
        <property name="build.include.all.scss" value="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

To recap, running **sencha app watch** and loading the page will show the listeners for the Ext.Ajax singleton, but running **sencha app build production** and loading the page will show no listeners. And no, I do not wish to create my own version of Ext.Ajax or my own data proxy... I realize that's probably the right approach, but there is a lot of code where I'd have to replace that, and that would be a whole lot of regression testing that I currently don't have time for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may've figured it out, but it might be inefficient.  What I did was update the Build.xml file to include the page, and changed the output write path for the framework.js file to where app.js is.  Then I updated app.json to change the path of where the framework node gets written.  Not sure why I'd have to change both places, and I almost feel like it writes framework.js into app.js, and then overwrites it later on... so that might be inefficient, but this does seem to work.

```
<x-compile refid="${compiler.ref.id}">
    <![CDATA[
    union
      -r
      -class=${app.name}.view.main.Main
    and
    save
      viewport
    and
    intersect
      -set=viewport,allframework
    and
    include
      -set=frameworkdeps
    and
    save
      frameworkdeps
    and
    include
      -tag=Ext.cmd.derive
    and
    // added this
    include
      -set=page
    and
    concat
      -remove-text-references=${build.remove.references}
      -optimize-string-references=${build.optimize.string.references}
      -remove-requirement-nodes=${build.remove.requirement.nodes}
      ${build.compression}
      // changed this
      -out=${build.classes.file}
      ${build.concat.options}
    and
    restore
      viewport
    and
    exclude
      -set=frameworkdeps
    and
    exclude
      -set=page
    and
    exclude
      -tag=Ext.cmd.derive,derive
    and
    concat
      -remove-text-references=${build.remove.references}
      -optimize-string-references=${build.optimize.string.references}
      -remove-requirement-nodes=${build.remove.requirement.nodes}
      ${build.compression}
      -out=${build.out.base.path}/${build.id}/viewport.js
      ${build.concat.options}
    ]]>
</x-compile>
```

Then in the output node in app.json:

```
"framework": {
  // Added this path
  "path": "${build.id}/app.js",
  "enable": true
}
```